# Phaser 3: Play animation after previous animation finished

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I tried playing an animation after the previous animation is finished using the `animationcomplete` event. However that event seems to trigger on the animation inside the event itself as well, causing an endless loop.

How can I play two subsequent animations instead?

```
character.sprite.play("ball_out").on('animationcomplete', () => {
    character.sprite.play("feather_in");
});
```

Comment: The event listener isn't added to the animation but to the sprite, that's what causes the loop.

Comment: @ChrisG how exactly could I add the event listener to the animation itself?

Comment: I don't think you can; you can either use .once() like you found or for more complex stuff keep a state variable to determine whether to play the next animation or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently using

```
character.sprite.play("ball_out").once('animationcomplete', () => {
   character.sprite.play("feather_in");
});
```

fixed the issue! (Note the `once` in lieu of `on`)